# WPF - drawing text onto a GridSplitter

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

I am declaring this Grid Splitter:

```
<GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext">
    </GridSplitter>
```

It is a vertical grid splitter and I want to draw some text using RotateTransform so the text runs from top to bottom.  I am having trouble getting it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should render the text as rotated.

```
<TextBlock Text="Testing" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

You would then need to include it after your GridSplitter in the same column. The IsHitTestVisible is just in case it interferes with the mouse.

EDIT: Just to be clear, this would be a child of the Grid, not the GridSplitter. It would simply render on top of the GridSplitter.